# MySQL Query: How can I add a user to my MySQL database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I add a user to my MySQL database with PHP. This doesn't add a user.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, password, realname) 
            VALUES ('$myusername', '$mypassword', '$myrealname'");
```

What seems to be the problem with my query?

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the closing bracket for VALUES

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, password, realname) 
            VALUES ('$myusername', '$mypassword', '$myrealname')");
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, this code looks dangerous. You escaped everything before to prevent SQL injection, or you are in a very save environment?

Answer (score -1):

Your double quotes should be after the closing bracket.